# singular or plural verbs for compound nouns and modifiers

Tags: compound-subjects

I am confused why the compound noun has the singular verb "HAS" in the modifier clause "which has won awards..." and the plural verb "HAVE" as the main verb.

Should I use plural or singular verb as the verb in the main and modifier clause?

A national supermarket chain and a locally owned bakery, which **HAS** won awards for its crosissants, **HAVE** seen a significant decrease in the revenue since the biggest employer in the area shut down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read it this way:

> A national supermarket chain and a locally owned bakery (which HAS won awards for its crosissants[sic]) HAVE seen a significant decrease in the revenue since the biggest employer in the area shut down.

The *has* applies to a bakery and *have* to both:  the supermarket chain **and** bakery.

Check [restrictive and non-restrictive clauses here.](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/restrictive_clause.htm)

Comment: How do I determine whether the non-restrictive clause applies to both the compound nouns or individual noun, as shown in this case.

Comment: The *string* between the commas. The comma before *which* and after *crosissants[sic].*

Comment: in this case, how do I write a restrictive clause for both the supermarket and bakery? I am trying understand how does it make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The HAS modifies 1) a locally owned bakery. 
The HAVE modifies 1)a national supermarket chain and 2)a locally owned bakery